# ComboBox cargado con imágenes (JSwing)

Tags: java, java-swing, combobox, interfaz-gráfica

Saludos, llevo buscando la solución a este problema desde hace una semana y me he visto obligado a comentar por aquí la duda, ya que no encuentro la información necesaria para resolverla. Dejo claro de antemano que soy muy principiante en el mundo de la programación y es la primera aplicación con interfaz gráfica que he hecho o eso estoy intentando.

Resulta que estoy intentando cargar un JComboBox con imágenes, pero solo con imágenes sin nada de texto (visible en la parte de la interfaz de usuario) asociado a ellas, he intentado usar la interfaz de "ListCellRenderer", pero creo que no llego a comprender del todo la interfaz, ya que con mi código actual tan solo me carga 1 de las 8 imágenes que debería cargarme. Este es el codigo:

```
public class EficienciaJcbModel extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer{
private ArrayList<Eficiencia> ale = new ArrayList<Eficiencia>();

public EficienciaJcbModel(ArrayList<Eficiencia> _ale){
    this.ale = _ale;
}

@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/iconosclasificacionenergetica/"+ ale.get(index+1).getIcono())));
    return this;
}
```

El arraylist que tiene como atributo la clase, está cargado con el nombre de las imágenes con el fin de pasarlas como un recurso al método que carga las dichas imágenes. Al array le paso el indice, para que cargue la posicion 0 con el nombre de la imagen en la poscion 0 del array, la posicion 1 con el nombre de la imagen en la posicion 1 del array...

En vista de no entender muy bien la documentación de esta interfaz, he probado a usar la interfaz del ComboBoxModel, pero tan solo abarco el concimiento de como crear un modelo personalizado de una tabla y no llego a comprender realmente el ComboBoxModel (se asemeja al tableModel, pero no consigo adaptar la similitud al caso).

Aquí está el código de las clases que uso para que cargue 1 de las 8 imágenes:

```
public void cargarEficiencias(JComboBox jcbEficiencias) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    ArrayList<Eficiencia> ale = new ArrayList<Eficiencia>();
    GestorEficiencias geficiencias = new GestorEficiencias();
    ale = geficiencias.consultarEficiencias();
    jcbEficiencias.setRenderer(new EficienciaJcbModel(ale));
}
```

ACTUALIZACIÓN

He conseguido añadir todas las imágenes añadiendo al JComboBox items antes de usar el método **setRenderer()**, sin embargo aun añadiendo todas las imágenes,
estas no son seleccionables... Dejo una captura de pantalla a continuación:

[image: JComboBox cargado con imágenes no seleccionables, el código de la clase EficienciaJcbModel sigue siendo el mismo]

**JComboBox cargado con imágenes no seleccionables**, el código de la clase EficienciaJcbModel sigue siendo el mismo.

Así cargo el combobox:

```
JComboBox<String> jcbEficiencia = new JComboBox();
    jcbEficiencia.setToolTipText("");
    jcbEficiencia.setBounds(330, 39, 175, 20);
    add(jcbEficiencia);
    jcbEficiencia.addItem("A");
    jcbEficiencia.addItem("B");
    jcbEficiencia.addItem("C");
    jcbEficiencia.addItem("D");
    jcbEficiencia.addItem("E");
    jcbEficiencia.addItem("F");
    jcbEficiencia.addItem("G");
```

Pero si quiero meter el ultimo valor, es decir, un item más me da error:
`JComboBox<String> jcbEficiencia = new JComboBox();
        jcbEficiencia.setToolTipText("");
        jcbEficiencia.setBounds(330, 39, 175, 20);
        add(jcbEficiencia);
        jcbEficiencia.addItem("A");
        jcbEficiencia.addItem("B");
        jcbEficiencia.addItem("C");
        jcbEficiencia.addItem("D");
        jcbEficiencia.addItem("E");
        jcbEficiencia.addItem("F");
        jcbEficiencia.addItem("G");
        jcbEficiencia.addItem("NA");`

Este error:[image: Error]

Dice que se sale del array pero mi array tiene 8 String con el nombre de los iconos...

Gracias por vuestro tiempo, un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Añade al `JComboBox` los ítems que quieras y que sean de texto normal. Puede ser la letra de la eficiencia `A`, `B`, `C` o lo que quieras, porque no se van a ver.

Para que no se vean, tienes que cambiar el *Render*. Como lo tienes está bien, cuando el `JComboBox` va a pintar un ítem, pregunta al render cómo pintarlo. El render por defecto hace un `toString()` del ítem, con lo que verías `A`, `B`, `C`, pero si tu pones uno que devuelve un `JLabel` con una imagen, verás la imagen y no el texto.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de [imágenes en `JCombobox`](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Poner_iconos_en_un_JCombobox).

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el contenido relevante de tu página en la respuesta? Creo que es una buena respuesta a la que le falta un ejemplo de código, que haría toda la diferencia.

Comment: No entiendo... tengo que cambiar el Render, pero a la vez como lo tengo está bien, pero no me funciona...

Comment: El render que tienes esta bien, de hecho pinta las imagenes, no creo que haga falta cambiarlo. Sospecho mas bien del tipo de items que metes en el JCombobox. ¿Puedes poner ese código?

Comment: Si claro, edito el post para meter el codigo donde cargo el JComboBox

Comment: No puedes meter mas items que los que tengas en el array del render. Si añades mas items, los ultimos no sabra como pintarlos

Answer (score 0):

Un JComboBox te permite mostrar Objetos en una lista desplegable, la manera más común de usarla es de tipo String, pero lo puedes hacer con otros objetos. En este caso se puede usar un objeto de tipo ImageIcon de la siguiente manera JComboBox, donde dices que es un JComboBox de objetos ImageIcon, parcido a un ArrayList de Objetos. Haces la declaración, añades un item ImageIcon, el cual contiene la ruta y pues en este caso va directamente en un Frame.

[image: Imágen de código fuente]

Es un ejémplo básico donde se añade una imágen a un JComboBox.

Espero sirva a quién interese y si es posible a quien preguntó.